# how to create log in page for my project using angular?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am using angular.js for the very first time and really getting confused as to how to start. Any advices and/or resources are very much appreciated. 
I'm trying to create log in page but now I'm struggling and I've been researching and I'm not winning. Can anyone help me please in my project.

**Person model**

```
public partial class Person1
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserAuthRoleId { get; set; }
}
```

**Password model**

```
public partial class Password
{
    public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }    
    public string Password1 { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

**app.js**

```
   var Call23 = angular.module("Call23", ["ngResource", "ngRoute", 'ui.bootstrap']).
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: LoginCtrl, templateUrl: 'login.html' }).


        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

   Call23.factory("page", function($rootScope){
       var page={};
       var user={};
       page.setPage=function(title,bodyClass){
           $rootScope.pageTitle = title;
           $rootScope.bodylayout=bodyClass;
       };
       page.setUser=function(user){
           $rootScope.user=user;
       }
       return page;
   });

   var LoginController = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, LoginFactory) {
       $scope.loginForm = {
           UserName: '',
           password: '', 
           returnUrl: $routeParams.returnUrl,
           loginFailure: false,
           loginSucess: false
       };


       $scope.login = function () {

           var result = LoginFactory($scope.loginForm.UserName, $scope.loginForm.password, $scope.loginForm.rememberMe);
           result.then(function (result) {
               if (result.success) {
                   if ($scope.loginForm.returnUrl !== undefined) {
                       $location.path('/');
                   }
                   else {
                       $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
                   }
                   $scope.loginForm.loginSucess = true;
               } else {
                   $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
               }
          });
     }
  }
var LoginFactory = function ($http, $q) {
return function (UserName, Password) 
    var deferredObject = $q.defer();
    $http.post(
       'login.html', {
            Email: UserName,
            Password: Password,
        }
    ).
    success(function (data) {
        if (data == "True") {
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: true });
        } else {
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: false });
        }
    }).
    error(function () {
        deferredObject.resolve({ success: false });
    });
    return deferredObject.promise;
}
}
LoginFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
```

**html**

```
<input id="UserName" type="text" class="form-control" name="UserName" data-ng-model="vm.userName" placeholder="username or email">

<input id="Password" type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="password" data-ng-model="vm.password">
```

I do not know how to proceed from my app.js code now.

Comment: I have a feeling your post may get down voted - you need to mention where you are getting stuck - "I've been researching and not winning" is not a valid question or a problem. Let us know which step of the login process are you at and what you did, what problem you are facing and we can help.

Comment: @callmekatootie can you please check the upsated code then

Comment: You need to format your code properly - correct the indentation. I am not familiar with c# btw.

Comment: But where are you exactly stuck? Also, check that you're initializing the app (with ng-app or manual bootstrap) and that you're also setting your controller

Comment: `var result = LoginFactory ....`  Where is the `LoginFactory` code?

Comment: ok, so that makes sense; now back to the original statement made by others... what exactly isn't working? are you getting an error? are you not receiving data from your server? is you server not receiving the data from the client? It's not easy for us to guess at what you might consider to be a challenge, and you still haven't actually asked a question, only statements that you are confused and that you don't know how to proceed.   Not knowing how to proceed is frustrating, but it isn't actually a question.

Comment: @AndrewCounts my problem is that im not sure if i ve done the right thing or not. and when im trying to loging i ve this Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LoginFactoryProvider <- LoginFactory

Comment: also trying to ask if there is nothing that i left off in my code